# Django CMS Module URL Issue

Tags: django, django-cms

I am working with my first django cms project (coming from a DNN background) and I am quite confused by the plugins.

I am trying to create a simple plugin to display a user profile based on the id passed in the url. '/profile/1' where /profile is my page and the id is 1.  I created the module and added it to my profile page, but when I try to add the /1 to the url, I get a 404.  So, I created an app hook and a urls.py in the application that looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from user_profile import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<profile_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

My views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


def detail(request, profile_id):

    return render_to_response('profile_view.html', {}, RequestContext(request))
```

Here is my template for this module:

```
{% extends CMS_TEMPLATE %}
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}
{% block content %}
<h1>PROFILE</h1>
<p>
    Name =  {{ request.user.id }}
</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

But..now when I hit that url, it strips away my cms skin and shows only the template for the profile view.  What am I missing?  I want the page to render around my plugin.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `profile_view.html` template? Does it extend the base template file for your project?

Comment: I have now edited in my template.